# Response.write doesn't display the image

Tags: asp.net, html

Writing html using Response.Write in asp.net it doesn't display the image. I check my image path code and simple put it in the page and it works fine. Why it doesn't display the image when writing using response.write code.
Following is my image path code

```
<img alt="" src="<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/images/txt2.png")%>" border="0"/>
```

This is Response.write code

```
<% Response.Write(valueHelp); %>
```

ValueHelp is a string which contain the image code which i have mention above.

Any idea why it is not working?
Thanks in advance

Comment: How do the two piece of code fit together?  There is nothing obvious

Comment: Value help is a string which contain image html which i have written above

Comment: Can you show us (by **editing** your question) exactly how `valueHelp` is constructed?

Comment: Instead of value help just try using <% Response.Write("test"); %> and let us know whether it prints "test" or not.

Comment: @user1501472 it works i tried but getting problem in case of image only

Comment: Please show us the generated HTML.

Comment: tell me how you are binding/inserting value in valuehelp variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`<%= %>` is to be used within the mark-up (i.e. the HTML part of your code) and not in the code-behind.

My guess (without seeing the code) is that you are actually sending `<%= VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/images/txt2.png")%>` to the browser as part of a static string.

So instead of it being picked up by the server and rendered into the correct path, it is simply being sent as part of the HTML to the browser (the browser not knowing what on earth it means, therefore it will not show the image you expect).

Try something like this when you are creating the `valueHelp` string

```
valueHelp = "<img alt='' src='" + VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/images/txt2.png") + "' border='0'/>";
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```
<% Response.Write("<img alt='' src='" +
    VirtualPathUtility.ToAbsolute("~/Content/images/txt2.png") +
 "' border='0'/>" ); %>
```